# Why can't Knockout custom components be named and registered in camelCase?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have started working on Knockout recently, and have been assigned to create custom components that can be used in various application. While creating a component, I used camel case to name it, e.g: "`datePicker`".

### Component code

```
ko.components.register("datePicker",{
    viewModel: require('./components/date-picker-widget'),
    template: require('raw!./components/date-picker-widget.html')
});
```

#### HTML Code

```
<datePicker params="{value:returnValue, initialValue:returnValue.initialValue}"></datePicker>
```

But this is what was rendered:

[image: HTML Code rendered]

So its clear that Knockout expects component names in lower case ([JSFiddle reference](http://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/L8dxvh66/)). The question remains is why?

I also saw similar constraints on naming of components in React, where you have to start the name with capital character only.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of rewording your title slightly, so that it IMO matches the actual question better and will be easier to find when others are searching for the same issue. If you feel I was incorrect in doing so feel free to revert / improve.

Comment: I think this one is more descriptive. Also thanks for such detailed answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is [here in the documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-custom-elements.html#controlling-custom-element-tag-names):

> By default, Knockout assumes that your custom element tag names correspond exactly to the names of components registered using ko.components.register. This convention-over-configuration strategy is ideal for most applications.
>
> If you want to have different custom element tag names, you can override getComponentNameForNode to control this. For example,
>
> ```
> ko.components.getComponentNameForNode = function(node) {
>     var tagNameLower = node.tagName && node.tagName.toLowerCase();
>
>     if (ko.components.isRegistered(tagNameLower)) {
>         // If the element's name exactly matches a preregistered
>         // component, use that component
>         return tagNameLower;
>     } else if (tagNameLower === "special-element") {
>         // For the element <special-element>, use the component
>         // "MySpecialComponent" (whether or not it was preregistered)
>         return "MySpecialComponent";
>     } else {
>         // Treat anything else as not representing a component
>         return null;
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> You can use this technique if, for example, you want to control which subset of registered components may be used as custom elements.

In fact, the documentation is not entirely up to par with the code, because it claims "correspond exactly", whereas in fact in the code only the tag name is lowercased, and the registration isn't.

In any case, [because browsers return `tagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/tagName) in upper case, the above code will only work if your registration is in lowercase.

So, [you can](http://jsfiddle.net/zddse7kp/) either use `datePicker` camelCased in your view and register it lower case:

```html
<datePicker></datePicker>
```

```javascript
ko.components.register("datepicker",{
    viewModel: function() { },
    template: '<strong>DatePicker stub is showing!</strong>'
});

$(function() { ko.applyBindings({}); });
```

Or you [can monkey patch](http://jsfiddle.net/tzm1r212/) the register function:

```html
<datePicker></datePicker>
```

```javascript
var originalFn = ko.components.register;

ko.components.register = function(name, options) {
    originalFn(name.toLowerCase(), options);
};

ko.components.register("datePicker",{
    viewModel: function() { },
    template: '<strong>DatePicker stub is showing!</strong>'
});

$(function() { ko.applyBindings({}); });
```

Though I'm not sure how stable and cross-browser compatible that would be.

In any case that shouldn't matter much, since you merely asked "why" this was like it was.

My suggestion: stick to the docs' style of `dash-cased-element-names`.

PS. The screenshot you posted is how the *debugger* rendered your elements, not how Knockout or the browser would have it. In fact, most likely if you use "view source" you'll get a camelCased element name; to be entirely sure you could inspect the raw body of the request.

Answer (score 2):

Its not just the case with knockoutjs or react components, if you are writing xHTML then according to the specification tag names and attributes must be in lower case. (Ref: http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.2).

In most browsers, although the rendered html will have case insensitive tags (View Source), but the DOM built by browser(debugger tools, inspect element) will usually have all lowercase for tag names and attributes.

Although there is no wrong with case insensitive tags and attribute names, the web developers have, IMO, just adopted the convention of using lowercase names for XHTML or HTML.

Comment: You make a decent point, and may have the key to the answer, but it *seems* from the jsfiddle that OP is using html5, not xhtml (nearly no one is *actually* using xhtml anyways...).